# How could I prevent NetExtender Cli to asking certificate confirmation?

Tags: linux, sonicwall, self-signed-certificate

Our company is using self-signed *SonicWall* for firewall facility. And remote clients needs to be connect to internal network through *VPN* via *NetExtender* client.

Some of the clients are using *Linux OS* without *Desktop Environment* on purpose.

There is an issue occurring with *NetExtender* Client at those *no Desktop Environment* computers on each connection attempt.

On each connection attempt *NetExtender* client need to be approved for this question:

> Warning: self signed certificate
>
> Do you want to proceed? (Y:Yes, N:No, V:View Certificate)

I read about self-signed certificates from this [link](http://help.mysonicwall.com/sw/eng/2531/ui2/2500/NetExtender.html)

Than I try to install `/home/$USER/.netExtenderCerts/PUB_CERT/ca-bundle.crt` file by copying to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and using `update-ca-certificiates` command.

```
# cp /home/$USER/.netExtenderCerts/PUB_CERT/ca-bundle.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
# update-ca-certificates 
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
1 added, 0 removed; done.
```

After applying this method and rebooted the OS, *NetExtender Client* still hanging at same question. This were preventing to build automated connection.

How could I prevent netExtender client to asking this question?

Comment: Use a godaddy or a free ssl cert ?

Comment: If I could, I would. But I can't, so I shan't. :)

Comment: Does `/home/$USER/.netExtenderCerts/PUB_CERT/ca-bundle.crt` contain the correct certificate?

Answer (score 4):

To prevent NetExtender's certificate verification dialogue, you can use the undocumented switch `"--always-trust"`

For example:

```
netExtender -u user -p password -d 'domain' --always-trust host
```

Tested on Linux, but I'm not sure about NetExtender Windows CLI.

**Note:** as commented by Håkan Lindqvist, take into consideration that this will open up for MITM attacks.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to where you found this flag? Is there additional documentation aside from what is listed on NetExtender's documentation site?

Comment: @Xenology No, I don't know where you can find this flag elsewhere, neither extra documentation, unfortunately.

Comment: This does work, I can confirm

Comment: Does not work in newer versions 835+ (for linux at least).

Answer (score 2):

Håkan Lindqvists comment is on the money.

Only the certificates contained in `~/.netExtenderCerts/PUB_CERT/ca-bundle.crt` seem to be evalutated by netExtender. The good news is this is a text file containing Base64 encoded certificates, so it's quite straightforward to add yours to the file.

First you need to get a copy of the certificate. You can do this by opening the vpn server address in a browser, (right-)clicking on the padlock icon next to the url, inspect the certificate and then exporting it. Save the certificate as `Base64-encoded ASCII, single certificate` or something equivalent.

I recommend backing up the original `ca-bundle.crt` file, just in case the next step fails or you wish to revert your certificates.

Finally, combine the exported certificate and backup into a single file and save as `ca-bundle.crt`

*Disclaimer: I found no documentation for this, so my solution is based on experimentation*

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/bash
echo Y | netExtender -u user -p password -d 'domain' host
```

Comment: While that may get rid of the question, it would also open up for MITM attacks.

Comment: I tried this method.  The other problem is if you lose connection and try to re-connect, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The netExtender GUI creates `/home/$USER/.netextender` with contents in the following format:

```
[trustedcerts]
<ip>:<port>=<fingerprint>
```

Create this file manually and replace the ip, port, and fingerprint with your values. (To get the fingerprint, type `V` to view the certificate, then copy all of `SHA1[...]`.)